# What happens to the Fragment Back Stack on screen rotation?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on a project that requires me to manage the flow between multiple different Fragments and I was considering using the back stack to do this, but I wanted to first double check about screen rotation and the state of the back stack.

If I rotate the screen of my phone, do I need to be aware of any special interactions that happen with respect to the back stack or can I just push/pop away as if the screen didn't rotate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the back stack isn't affected when the screen is rotated. The back stack is only affected when you use:

```
transaction.addToBackStack();
```